# Is is possible to create an alert box between two flask routes?

Tags: python, flask

I have two flask routes,

route one is an HTML form( `route_one.html` ) that has a set of products and qty with a button to update `qty`. Upon hitting update the qty is updated and sent to route two

```
  <form method="POST" action="/update">
    <input type="number" value= qty>
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
  </form>
```

route two (/update)is a simple flask function that checks the `qty` of `route_one.html` to see if it is above `n`.

```
n = 100
if qty > n:
    print("over 100")

 return ('',204)
```

Is there a way to make an alert box if the `qty` is over n, without leaving `route_one.html` ?

I attempted to use `flash` messages, but since the routes are separate this will not work. In this case, the routes must be seperate.

Comment: You'd need something like AJAX to do it. Yes it's possible, but flask needs to respond to the frontend to say something didn't work (and `flash` probably won't cut it)

Comment: You can use javascript, simply. Google "how to validate your data before being submitted". Add "javascript" to your search...